# Can SELinux defend against DLL injection?

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I am confused about the security evaluation of SELinux. Can it defend against DLL injection, or other hack technologies?

Comment: Sometimes. You'd need wine for that and a whitelist of DLLs.:)

Comment: What do you mean by DLL injection?

Comment: More appropriate on http://security.stackexchange.com, however this question needs work so it is clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLLs are libraries used on Windows.

SELinux concerns - as the name states - Linux.

The two don't overlap for any practical purposes unless you use Wine or something else more obscure.

Now, if you are asking if SELinux can prevent the placement of manipulated .so files, then that depends. If it is correctly configured, it should prevent unauthorised users from overwriting local libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much.I am not very family about security. In fact, what I want to know is that if SELinux is configured correctly, is it still can be attacked by hacker? Or is it still can be hacked by software ? As I have know that trustzone can not be hacked by software. I am just begin to study the security things.

Comment: There is no such thing as "secure". It may be more or less difficult to compromise a target and it may take more or less resources to do so. I recommend attending Infosec conferences and/or viewing free recordings of them online (available for several Defcon / HITB events) to get into the basic grove of things. SELinux is a line of defence but not intrinsically perfect or secure. If configured too strictly, the system becomes unusable. If configured too loosely, it doesn't present a defence. The right configuration depends on the target. Just "using SELinux" doesn't mean much.